# How to uninstall SIMATIC STEP 7-Micro/WIN V4.0.8.06?

Tags: software, pneumatic

I recently installed **SIMATIC STEP 7-Micro/WIN V4.0.8.06** but cancelled the installation after some steps.

But the program appears in the control panel and when I try to uninstall it, the error:- "*Did not find Shared Comm client list in registry at:.....*" appears and the unistallation process terminates.

I also tried to uninstall the registry entries by opening  "*HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE > SOFTWARE*" directory.
Still it won't uninstall.

Please help!!

Answer (score 1):

Your best bet, if Control Panel/Add or Remove programs isn't working, is to navigate to your STEP 7 Micro/WIN directory in the Windows Explorer and delete it (default directory: `C:\Program Files\Siemens\STEP 7 MicroWIN V4.0`).

To remove the registry items associated with STEP 7:

Go to:
`HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE \ Software \ Microsoft \ Windows \ CurrentVersion \ Uninstall.`

Click the  `Uninstall` folder and go to `Edit > Find`

Enter: `STEP 7 Micro/WIN`

Check whether the `DisplayName` code matches one of the "MicroWin Release" versions i.e. `V4.0.8.06`. Delete the corresponding folder...

Refer to [this](https://support.industry.siemens.com/cs/document/14618173/how-do-you-uninstall-step-7-micro-win-v4-0-after-an-aborted-installation-?dti=0&lc=en-RU) document for help.